# How do I drop this table in Derby?

Tags: mysql, derby, myeclipse

I have a table called Rating. It was linked to another Table called Movie by a foreign key, which I deleted.
I used this query: "drop table movie_site.rating;".
It gave me this error: Operation 'DROP CONSTRAINT cannot be performed on object ##### because CONSTRAINT 'RATING_ID' is dependent on that object.
This is in myEclipse.
Thanks.

Comment: You dropped the foreign key constraint or the other table? What commands have you issued?

Comment: I dropped the foreign keys and that is all. If you can share how to drop the schema it is in, that would work as well.

Comment: I this a question about MySQL, or about Derby? You tagged it with both.

Comment: I have already fixed the issue, but it would appear not all of MySQL is recognized by Derby, at least not in the version I am using.